# Android screenshot of OpenGl screen

Tags: android, opengl-es, screenshot

I work on library that has to take screenshots. This library can be used by other applications, also it can be opengl application. Currently library can take screenshot using drawing cache of view.  For opengl screens I use the way, that requires rooted devices. The problem is that I can't get Gl context of current application from my framework. And I want to find the way to capture screen without root permissions.

Comment: I don't quite get what you are trying to do. Do you want with the OpenGLES app to capture a screenshot of the android device?

Comment: No. I want from my framework capture current screen of application. And this application can use OpenGl for rendering.

Comment: did you try `glReadPixels()` ?

Comment: I don't have access to GL context. I develop only module(library, framework - jar file). Any other application can use it. So I can't access Gl context from my code.

Comment: Android is a strict OS, you don't have access to the rendering surfaces in a direct manner at all. The only way to go about it is to read it from /dev/fb0 which cannot be done without a rooted phone.